# Overlapping panels with "Dock" resize functionality

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been struggling for a couple of days with this issue, which seems like it would have an obvious solution.
How could I place a panel, which maintains position and resizes as if Docked, in the middle of the form, over other panels populating a TableLayoutPanel without messing Column/Row spans and misplacing other containers and controls?

I would like to avoid developing custom functionality and make due with the basic visual studio toolbox (extensions are welcome).

In an effort to better explain what I'm hoping to achieve, I've provided a link to an image of the goal.

**Blue** is the dynamically resizable, centered pop-up panel.
**Green** is an Image/BackgroundImage starting on cell [1,1] of the TableLayoutPanel.
**Orange** is a drop-down panel for a side menu, also starting on cell [1,1].

[image: image of desired form layout]

Comment: Anchor it on all sides and set a MinimumSize (and a MaximumSize, if required), maybe?

Comment: @Jimi, the problem with combining Left and Right Anchoring is that the panel tries to maintain absolute pixel distance from the edges of its parent container.
So if the parent Form's width starts at 100px and the Panel at 50px, the Panel is 50% of total width.
If we then set the Form width to 200px the panel will become 150px, in order to maintain the initial side distance and is now 75% of total width.
I'm trying to avoid developing custom functionality if I can help it!

Comment: I suggested to anchor it on all sides, not just Left / Right. I assumed you wanted to keep the same distance from the Top. When you have this kind of layout, you set either the MinimumSize of the Form or a combination of Minimum/Maximum size of the Form and the child Controls - but it's just a supposition, I don't know what kind of layout you're looking for. You can also handle the Resize event of your Form, but...

Comment: @Jimi, the same applies to Anchoring on all sides. The rate of growth is 1 to 1 that way. Resizing an initially 100x100 Form with a 80x80 Panel child, to a 1000x1000 Form would make the child 980x980. I would like the Panel to maintain the initial dimension ratio the way it would if Docked in a TableLayoutPanel cell of which its Column length and Row height are 80%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I found a solution.
I guess I needed to admit that I have to write the resizing function myself.
I'm new here, so I don't know if answering oneself question is canon, but here goes.

For the **Orange** panel, given it's Anchored Top,Left:

```
private double panel1WidthRatio, panel1HeightRatio; // Global variables for maintaining ratio.

    private void ParentForm_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double p1w = this.side_panel.Size.Width;    // Grab the panels' dimensions
        double p1h = this.side_panel.Size.Height;   // as soon as the user begins to resize
        double fw = this.Size.Width;                // in order to store
        double fh = this.Size.Height;               // the Panel to Form
        panel1WidthRatio = p1w / fw;                // dimension ratios.
        panel1HeightRatio = p1h / fh;
    }

    private void ParentForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double formWidth = this.Size.Width;         // As soon as a new size is set
        double formHeight = this.Size.Height;       // resize the panel using the earlier ratio.
        this.side_panel.Size = new Size((int)(formWidth * panel1WidthRatio), (int)(formHeight * panel1HeightRatio));
    }
```

For the Blue panel, given no Anchors, simply replace:

```
this.side_panel.Size = new Size((int)(formWidth * panel1WidthRatio), (int)(formHeight * panel1HeightRatio));
```

with:

```
        this.middle_panel.Size = new Size((int)(formWidth * panel2WidthRatio), (int)(formHeight * panel2HeightRatio));
        this.middle_panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Size.Width/4-9, this.Size.Height/4-24);
```

The constants (9,24) take into account the Form's frame and borders, so as to correctly reposition the panel in the center.